# Is there a way to trigger precision failed of double / float number only using addition or subtraction

Tags: floating-point, double, precision

Float and double commonly represented using IEEE 754. And this create some number such as 0.1 not represented correctly by system and may trigger precision failed when multiplying and dividing.

Suppose we have system that store double number for currency calculation using only 2 decimal digit and only addition and subtraction operation. Is there a way to make this precision problem leak into 2 decimal digit?

Comment: Certainly. Add up enough (floating point approximations to) 0.1's and you'll get an answer as far as you want from the correct one. Why use floating point? Why not represent a money vaue as an intergral number of pennies (or cents or whatever)?

Comment: For currency, use a fixed format (generally, 4 decimal digits will do, so just use a long and scale it by 10000), or, if your language provides it, a BigDecimal, Currency or Money data type. They can all be rounded to two decimal digits without precision loss.

Comment: I'm the QA and I want to prove whenever the system is prone to the problem or not. If there is no way to cause trouble to the system, then it's not a problem and the implementation is declared as a sound implementation.

Comment: On my computer, in C, adding 1 billion 0.01 (in doubles) results in 9999999.83 (to two dp) rather than 10000000

Comment: Is there a specified upper limit on the amounts of money involved?